# Default time set in chageDate function

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker. If I choose any date means, its automatically taking current time(Hours and minutes). How to set the default time in bootstrap datetimepicker. Here, I want to set the default time inside of the "changeDate" function. I am using the following code,

```js
      $('#datetimepicker'+rowIndx).datetimepicker({
    format : "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm",           
    pickSeconds:false,   
  }).on("show",function(e) { 
      $('#datetimepicker'+rowIndx).datetimepicker("setDate", "");    
  }).on('changeDate', function(e) {            
             
   });
```

```
     Please explain me, how to set default "time" in "changeDate" function.
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be done by the next code:

```
$('#datetimepicker'+rowIndx).data("DateTimePicker").setDate(new Date());
```

[Check the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivangrs/4s5vorr2/)